How to change the fontsize of datepicker?
When I change the font size of the datepicker in CSS, the font icon mis-aligns.
I've been reading about SLDS and how it uses CSS tokens to do styling, but I couldn't figure out how to change this.
Any ideas how to do this properly using SLDS?

HTML Code
<div class="date-input">
    <lightning-input type="date" value="2024-04-04" variant="label-hidden" placeholder="Today" padding="around-small"></lightning-input>
</div>

CSS
.date-input { padding-top: 10px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; }
.date-input lightning-input { width: 160px; font-size: 20px; }


add your component and css code.

@DasariPrashanth added code
